# Loops and Dispatch Queue

Tags: swift2

I have a dispatch queue which has to be run infinitely. So am trying to have it in a do while loop so that the thread runs continuously, but when I tried to do it, I get a blank screen.

Below is the code:

```
    var i = 1
    do{
    dispatch.main(3)
    {
       self.myfunction()
    }
    i+=1
    }while(i>0)
```

I do not understand, why is it happening? and any idea on how to get a dispatch called every few seconds?

Comment: Are you running this code on the main thread?

Comment: yes, am running it on the main thread

Comment: If you run a while loop on the main thread indefinitely, you'll block the UI. This was the case with you as well.

Comment: ok, will try it on the other thread, but why is the question voted negative?

Comment: Because a simple googling would give you a lot of results on this. Shows that not enough research has been done before asking the question. :)

Comment: alright! .. thanks for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an extension of `NSTimer`, from [EZSwiftExtensions](https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions#nstimer-extensions).

```
extension NSTimer {
    public static func runThisEvery(seconds seconds: NSTimeInterval, handler: NSTimer! -> Void) -> NSTimer {
        let fireDate = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        let timer = CFRunLoopTimerCreateWithHandler(kCFAllocatorDefault, fireDate, seconds, 0, 0, handler)
        CFRunLoopAddTimer(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), timer, kCFRunLoopCommonModes)
        return timer
    }
}
```

What the code does is easy to understand. Create a run loop timer, add it to the run loop so it can actually run and fire, and return that instance so you can stop it later.

```
let timer = NSTimer.runThisEvery(seconds: 3) { _ in self.myFunction() }
```

to stop it, just:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Comment: Thanks that helped :)